# Push notification on vaadin 8.1 with liferay 7

Tags: liferay-7, vaadin8

I am using push notification on Vaadin 8.1 and it works well, but when I try use Liferay 7 with Vaadin 8.1 push notification doesn't work well and it gives me javax.portlet.PortletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Push is not available. see previous log messages for more information.
Is there a way use push notification on vaadin 8 with liferay 7 integration?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Vaadin Push does not work in a portlet environment and I haven't seen plans to make it fit.

I have found [this](https://github.com/Artur-/portal-push-liferay-example) sample app with push developed by a Vaadin guy for Liferay 6. For what I saw, this solution works only in single portlet apps.

Anyway, I suggest you to switch to a javascript-originated client polling, which creates a near-real-time push-like solution, using this simple and very well written extension [here](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/timerextension-add-on).